# Downgrade Linux Kernel - Invalid Module Format

Tags: drivers, kernel

I'm trying to install drivers for Duo3D Stereo Camera. However, the drivers are supported only till the version 4.4.0-75. I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux Kernel 4.10.0-35-generic.

I tried installing the 4.4.0-75 driver and got an error saying 'Invalid module format'. Now, how do I install these drivers? Should I downgrade my kernel? Are there any downsides to doing this? Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: are you installing from source?

Comment: I guess, I'm sorry I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm following the instructions from here: https://duo3d.com/docs/articles/install-linux

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you posted, the software comes with precompiled drivers.
Kernel modules (drivers) are compiled to run with specific kernels.

You have two options:

1) Install a supported kernel. Look in DUO3D-LIN-v1.0.80.20/DUODriver/ to see which kernels they have compiled for. You can have more that one kernel installed, so downgrading isn't necessary.
In grub, select "Advanced Options" and you can boot with the old kernel when you need to use DUO.

2) try to find the source code or dkms package for the driver so you can build it to your kernel.

Comment: Another good idea is to tell Grub to automatically boot the last menu selection after timeout. This way the newest kernel isn't automatically chosen and you have to reboot. Also good for automatic Windows update multiple rebooting.